# Rename [cuda-arrays] into [gpu-arrays]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

The [cuda-arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cuda-arrays) tag kind of sprang up at some point, and gathered a few items. Then today I decided to tag some more relevant questions with it and write a brief tag description - but as I was doing that, I realized I should probably have generalized the name into gpu-arrays, to also cover OpenCL "images", which are essentially the same thing but in the OpenCL naming scheme, which often clashes with CUDA's.

Now, it's true that most of the questions with that tag are CUDA-specific in some way, but - I don't think it would make sense to have a separate tag for the same concept in OpenCL; and the CUDA-specific questions have [cuda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cuda).

Hence I'm asking for a tag rename to `gpu-arrays`, and keeping `cuda-arrays` (and perhaps `opencl-images`) as aliases.

PS - The tag currently has 24 questions. I suspect there may be a few dozen more.